# Matrix multiplication with parallel programming in numpy python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, parallel-processing, multiplication

I'm new in python, but I need to convert normal matrix multiplication code to **parallel** with numpy,
I need to convert this function to parallel way:

```
def RowByColumn(A, B):
    matrix=[]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        matrix.append([])
        for j in range(len(B)):
            matrix[i].append(matrix_multiplication(getRow(A,i),getColumn(B,j)))
    return matrix
```

How can I to apply multiprocessing module or other parallel processing modules in python, could anyone help me how?

Comment: Does it need to be general matrix per matrix multiplication or matrix per vector?

Comment: Is this just an exercise in multiprocessing, or are you trying to improve on the speed of `AC@BC`?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to increase the speed and reduce the time using parallel programming with matrix multiplication in python.

Comment: Have you tried searching for something like "parallel processing with numpy"?

Comment: The builtin matrix multiplication uses compiled `BLAS` (or similar libraries) functions.  Those have been optimized, and may use low level parallel processing (depending on the system and library).  Python level multiprocessing is unlikely to improve on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend multiprocessing, as processes are slow to create, and also has a big communication overhead. You can use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/), which will compile your function and make it really fast. The library works really well with numpy. Also, it is very easy to include parallelization with threads:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def mat_mult(A, B):
    assert A.shape[1] == B.shape[0]
    res = np.zeros((A.shape[0], B.shape[1]), )
    for i in prange(A.shape[0]):
        for k in range(A.shape[1]):
            for j in range(B.shape[1]):
                res[i,j] += A[i,k] * B[k,j]
    return res

m, n, c = 1000, 1500, 1200
A = np.random.randint(1, 50, size = (m, n))
B = np.random.randint(1, 50, size = (n, c))

res = mat_mult(A, B)
```

Use `prange` to parallelize the loops. I have only parallelized the outer loop, but you can also apply this to the inner loops.

Note also the order of the loops I have used, which makes continuous memory accesses reducing cache misses.

In my laptop, the parallel function takes about 1.4 seconds to be executed, while numpy's matrix multiplication `A@B` takes 4.4 seconds, so there is some improvement.

Comment: Thank you, you explained it in simplest way!